# Mexcuda error on Windows 10 (Matlab 2016b)

Tags: matlab, visual-c++, cuda, installation, gpu

I'm using Windows 10, here is the compilers used by mex (as you can see I'm using Visual studio C++ 2015):

```
 >> mex -setup c++
  MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Professional' for C++ language compilation.

  Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB
     variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. In the near future
     you will be required to update your code to utilize the
     new API. You can find more information about this at:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.

  To choose a different C++ compiler, select one from the following:
  MinGW64 Compiler (C++)  mex -setup:'C:\Program Files\MATLAB_R2016b\bin\win64\mexopts\mingw64_g++.xml' C++
  Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Professional  mex -setup:C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2016b\mex_C++_win64.xml C++
```

And here is the result using gpuDevice:

```
>> gpuDevice

  ans = 

    CUDADevice with properties:

                        Name: 'Quadro M1000M'
                       Index: 1
           ComputeCapability: '5.0'
              SupportsDouble: 1
               DriverVersion: 8
              ToolkitVersion: 7.5000
          MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
            MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
          MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
                 MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
                   SIMDWidth: 32
                 TotalMemory: 2.1475e+09
             AvailableMemory: 1.6919e+09
         MultiprocessorCount: 4
                ClockRateKHz: 1071500
                 ComputeMode: 'Default'
        GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
      KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
            CanMapHostMemory: 1
             DeviceSupported: 1
              DeviceSelected: 1
```

And on Windows command prompt, the result when I checked for nvcc:

```
 C:\Users\LENOVO>nvcc --version
  nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
  Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
  Built on Mon_Jan__9_17:32:33_CST_2017
  Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.60
```

however there seems to be some warnings:

```
C:\Users\LENOVO>nvcc
  nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
  nvcc fatal   : No input files specified; use option --help for more information
```

Anyway, when I tried to use mexcuda to compile mexGPUExample.cu, an error showed up:

```
 >> mexcuda -v mexGPUExample.cu
  Warning: The selected C++ compiler is not supported for CUDA compilation. Searching for a supported
  compiler. 
  > In mexcuda (line 89) 
  Trying MEX options 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB_R2016b\toolbox\distcomp\gpu\extern\src\mex\win64\nvcc_msvcpp2013.xml'...FAILED
  Trying MEX options 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB_R2016b\toolbox\distcomp\gpu\extern\src\mex\win64\nvcc_msvcpp2012.xml'...FAILED
  Warning: No supported host compiler found, or other problem with the environment.
  Continuing with selected compiler to provide detailed diagnosis. 
  > In mexcuda (line 130) 
  mex -largeArrayDims -f C:\Program Files\MATLAB_R2016b\toolbox\distcomp\gpu\extern\src\mex\win64\nvcc_msvcpp2013.xml NVCC_FLAGS="" -v mexGPUExample.cu 
  Verbose mode is on.
  ... Looking for compiler 'NVIDIA CUDA Compiler' ...
  ... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 12.0 ...No.
  ... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 12.0 ...No.
  ... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 12.0 ...No.
  ... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 12.0 ...No.
  Did not find installed compiler 'NVIDIA CUDA Compiler'.
  Error using mex
  No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit
  http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2016b/win64.html.

  Error in mexcuda (line 157)
      [varargout{1:nargout}] = mex(mexArguments{:});
```

But I already installed Visual C++ 2015 compiler, which is supported by the CUDA compiler (according to : https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/270635-mexcuda-error-on-windows-10-matlab-2015-b) . I'm perplexed :(
Please help me, thank you very much

Comment: For supported CUDA compilers trust [NVIDIA better](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#axzz4brSkZdEj). However, your's should be supported. When I compile my .cu files, instead of using `mexcuda` I use `mex` and have a `.xml` file with the `nvcc` flags and other stuff. Have you tried that?

Comment: @AnderBiguri How do I setup this .xml file, can you give me the link?

Comment: Before trying that, try `mex -setup:C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2016b\mex_C++_win64.xml C++`. Else, check the [xml file here](https://github.com/CERN/TIGRE/blob/master/mex_CUDA_win64.xml). You may need to modify some paths and compiler flags. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB R2016b requires CUDA 7.5, which doesn't support Visual Studio 2015. So the first thing it's doing is checking for a version of Visual Studio you can use, which you don't have.

This Matlab Answer provides a workaround to force MATLAB to use CUDA 8.0 and Visual Studio 14:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/305391-compiling-cuda-files-with-mexcuda-why-wont-matlab-accept-my-compiler